# TCP Traffic Generator

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ip, simulation

I am searching for a TCP traffic generator. The problem is that I do not simply want to send TCP traffic as it can be done with e.g. Iperf. I want to be able to configure the flags and other header fields and I want to react on incoming packets e.g. a TCP SYN. 
So for example I want to send a TCP FIN packet if a TCP SYN arrives.

I prefer Linux tools but it would be also ok if the tool only runs under other OS.

I have looked into hping3, it looks promising. But I would like to look into other tools before choosing it.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be programming-related. Even if it were, it isn't a good fit for SO. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/185951.

Comment: You should write code to do that. It isn't hard.

Comment: Why don't you just write your own?

Comment: @ByronWhitlock, there is [no need to reinvent this wheel](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html)

Comment: I dont want to program that by my own. I still hope that there is a tool available.

Comment: @tobias, if you can be more specific about the problem you're solving I can elaborate on how to use `socat` for this

Comment: @Mike Pennington, thx for the link to socat. I have to look into it. As I wrote in my posting I want e.g. send with the tool a SYN packet, then I want to answer the SYN/ACK with a FIN. I want to use it as for robust testing of a tcp stack implementation..

Comment: @tobias, you said you wanted to configure flags and other header fields... that is what I'm asking about

Comment: @Mike, yes I want to set flags and other option fields in the tcp header, but I also want to react on incoming tcp packets e.g. a SYN with a defined behavior like sending a FIN.

Answer (score 0):

[SendIP](http://www.earth.li/projectpurple/progs/sendip.html) can generate TCP packets, with options to manipulate SYN/FIN bits as well as other fields.

This sort of question really belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).